# Nested callback function (React native JS )

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, expo

I have a couple of different functions that helps set different states of the component and i wish to run the functions in order of one another. I know that there are multiple posts on these but they seem to be mostly catered for running one function after the other but i have more than two functions that i need to execute in order

Desired order

1) Set state of starting and final destination

2) Run this.getDirections() (This function sets the state of arrOfPolylines which i desire to reset through  resetRouteSelectionStatus())

3) Run resetRouteSelectionStatus()

4) After running these functions i wish to have an empty this.state.arrOfPolylines

Actual results

There is no error in the code but it isnt entering the resetRouteSelectionStatus() as none of the console log are printed. Can someone please guide me on the right path?

```
    <Button
  onPress={() => { //on button press set final destination and starting location
    {
      (this.state.tempDestination.longitude != null && this.state.tempStarting.longitude != null) &&
        this.setState({
          finalDestination: {
            latitude: this.state.tempDestination.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.tempDestination.longitude,
          },
          startingLocation: {
            latitude: this.state.tempStarting.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.tempStarting.longitude,
          }
        }, () => {
              this.getDirections((this.state.startingLocation.latitude + "," + this.state.startingLocation.longitude), (this.state.finalDestination.latitude + "," + this.state.finalDestination.longitude),
              () => {this.resetRouteSelectionStatus()});
            }
            );

        }
      }}
      title="Determine Directions"
      color="#00B0FF"

      resetRouteSelectionStatus() {
    console.log('entered reset route selection status function')
    this.setState({arrOfPolyline: null }, () => {console.log("i should be null nd come first" + this.state.arrOfPolyline)}) ;
    this.setState({ selectChallengeStatus: null });
    this.setState({ userRouteSelectionStatus: null }); //when user click on button set seleection status to 0 so route options will be displayed again after generation new route
    //this.setState({arrOfDirectionDetails: []}); // clear past direction details when user select generate route with new  starting/ending location
    // clear past poly lines when user has selected new routes
    //console.log("everything has been reset");
  }




async getDirections(startLoc, destinationLoc) {
    let resp = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${startLoc}&destination=${destinationLoc}&key="KEY"&mode=driving&alternatives=true`)
    let respJson = await resp.json();
    let routeDetails = respJson.routes;
    let tempPolyLineArray = [];
    let tempDirArrayRoute = [];
    //console.log(startLoc);
    //console.log(destinationLoc);
    for (i = 0; i < routeDetails.length; i++) // respJson.routes = number of alternative routes available
    {
      let tempDirArray = []; // at every new route, initalize a temp direction array
      let points = Polyline.decode(respJson.routes[i].overview_polyline.points);
      let coords = points.map((point, index) => {
        return {
          latitude: point[0],
          longitude: point[1]
        }
      })
      tempPolyLineArray.push(coords);
      for (k = 0; k < routeDetails[i].legs[0].steps.length; k++) // for each route go to the correct route, enter legs ( always 0), get the number of instruction for this route
      {
        //console.log (routeDetails[i].legs[0].steps[k])
        tempDirArray.push(routeDetails[i].legs[0].steps[k]) // push all instructions into temp direction array
        //this.state.arrOfDirectionDetails.push(routeDetails[i].legs[0].steps[k]); // for each instruction save it to array
      }
      tempDirArrayRoute.push(tempDirArray); // at the end of each route, push all instructions stored in temp array as an array into state  
    }
    this.setState({ arrOfDirectionDetails: tempDirArrayRoute });
    this.setState({ arrOfPolyline: tempPolyLineArray });
    //creating my html tags
    let data = [];
    let temptitle = "Route ";
    for (let j = 0; j < routeDetails.length; j++) {
      data.push(
        <View key={j}>
          <Button
            title={temptitle + j}
            onPress={() => this.updateUser(j)}
          />
        </View>
      )
    }
    this.setState({ routebox: data })

  }
```

Comment: Can you share the getDirections code?

Comment: @AnasBakro i have edited it in

Answer (score 1):

So a few things to note here:

1. I would extract the inline function for the `onButtonPress` function into an `async` function

Something along the lines of:

```
const onButtonPressHandler = async () => {
 ... put your code here
}
```

Then you'll modify your `onButtonPress` to something like:

```
<Button
  onPress={this.onButtonPressHandler}
  ... rest of your props here
 />
```

You can then properly use async / await in the buttonPress handler.

2. The `setState` function is not a synchronous function. If you rely on the results right away you'll be disappointed.

Each time you call `setState` you could trigger a rerender.

I would instead merge all of your `setState` calls into a single at the end.

Comment: can i clarify why doesny the current method work? am i not implementing callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

The getDirections function does not include the callback, while it should be:

```
async getDirections(startLoc, destinationLoc, callback) {
.....
 this.setState({ routebox: data },callback());
}
```

or but not sure if it would be in order:

```
async () => {
              await this.getDirections((this.state.startingLocation.latitude + "," + this.state.startingLocation.longitude), (this.state.finalDestination.latitude + "," + this.state.finalDestination.longitude) );
             this.resetRouteSelectionStatus();
            }
```

You might need edit the resetRouteSelectionStatus to be:

```
resetRouteSelectionStatus = async ()=>{
```

Comment: can i clarify what is the callback suppose to be?  what value am i suppose to pass in

Comment: In you case it is resetRouteSelectionStatus as you passed it here this.getDirections(...,....,resetRouteSelectionStatus);

Comment: resetRouteSelectionStatus does not accept any input so no need to pass anything

Comment: ill give it a try as soon as i can, will upvote ur comment if it works!

Comment: any idea whats wrong with my current method though?